# Creating OOP decoupling with events

Tags: javascript

**Is Creating an app that communicates with events, from a infrastructure point, a good thing?** Or is better to just call methods and be simple, I was thinking about something as a observers pattern but in a large system. Other question, **this could affect the performance?** Here is a exemple is vanilla js:

### How it could work

```js
class someClass{

    someMethod() {
        let event =  new Event('event')
        document.dispatchEvent(event)
        console.log('ok');
    }

}

class otherClass {
    constructor(){
        this.initEventSearching();
    }

    initEventSearching(){
        document.addEventListener('event', () => {
            // block
            console.log('hey');
        })
    }
}

let aVariable = new someClass()
let bVariable = new otherClass()
aVariable.someMethod()
```

Comment: Since this question is an opinion-based design question it may be more suited for the Software Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: Seems counter intuitive to have a public `someMethod` that could eventually be recalled and even used by multiple instances. What I see happening is multiple events being dispatched to the `document`. Also, you won't know *who* dispatched the event. Not to talk about multiple instances listening to such Events... Would make more sense in a singleton, but as you presented it seems like a source of trouble on the long run.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, about knowing who dispatched the event, actually, I can use as a prop event  and call event.target to know who called the event. However, the whole propose about it is to the second class do not know who called the event, to them do not refer to each other and be decoupled

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, now I see this could be really slow but are you think the speed do not afford the deal about being so abstracted? And about singleton, I think that could really prevent being recalled and it makes really sense. thanks ^^. I will definitely implement it.

Comment: @Aurast, I did not know that this exists, I am sorry, I am just trying to dive deep in it and change ideas, learning everything ^^

Comment: @KauãAlves by *who* I didn't mean *"which Element in the DOM"*, but rather *which instance*. Such could be mitigated using `new CustomEvent("event", {detail: {instance: this}})`... It's really hard to answer in a meaningful way without knowing what aspect of a frontend app would those classes handle or in what context will be used. Creating a subscription model (EventEmitter) is not hard and it's used really often. Why not create instead an Emitter class and extend it where needed? There's also the useful Proxy... etc etc. I think I'm running out if characters in this comments section ;)

Comment: Suggestion ... implement an event bus once. Thus not a single instance of your type system has to feature/carry event target behavior, but every listening or dispatching type needs to know about and access the event bus, which makes the latter an integral part of your type system.